# Why is com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject throwing an exception on UWP but not on simulator?

Tags: uwp, codenameone

I have an externalize function that is working fine on Android, iOS and Simulator, but fails with an exception when running it on a UWP build that I'm trying to enable.

Can anyone tell me if this is normal and I just don't know something about externalizing on UWP, or if this is a bug we should open as an issue?

The code that causes it is:

```
@Override
public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Util.writeUTF(this.modSetVersion, out);
    Util.writeObject(getObjectsArrayFromLinkedHashMap(this.modules),out); //**Exception on this line
    Util.writeObject(getObjectsArrayFromLinkedHashMap(this.categories),out);
    Util.writeObject(this.learnables,out);
}

//Generates an array of objects from a LinkedHashMap to retain order in externalized file
private Object[] getObjectsArrayFromLinkedHashMap(LinkedHashMap lhm) {
    Set set = lhm.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    Object[] objList = new Object[set.size()];
    int i = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        objList[i++] = me.getValue();
    }
    return objList;
}
```

(Note that the objects in the array being externalized at Exception time (this.modules) are properly declared as externalizable and contain other objects that are externalizable, but from the stack trace it appears that it doesn't progress to the objects in this externalizable object before it fails)

**Stack Trace from logs captured on UWP Desktop client (Windows 10 Enterprise):**

```
[EDT] 0:1:15,155 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Object type not supported: [Ljava.lang.Object; value: [Ljava.lang.Object;@e08d4a

   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at UWPApp.IKVMReflectionHelper.getCurrentStackTrace()
   at java.lang.ThrowableHelper.getCurrentStackTrace()
   at java.lang.Throwable..ctor(String message)
   at java.lang.Exception..ctor(String message)
   at java.io.IOException..ctor(String message)
   at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Object o, DataOutputStream out)
   at trainingtoolDataModel.ModuleSet.externalize(DataOutputStream out)
   at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Object o, DataOutputStream out)
   at com.codename1.io.Storage.writeObject(String name, Object o)
   at userclasses.StateMachine.saveModuleSet(ModuleSet modSet)
   at userclasses.StateMachine.successfullyDownloadedAllAuthorizedContent(String retrievedVersion)
   at userclasses.StateMachine.updateContentFromNetwork(Boolean force)
   at userclasses.StateMachine.loadContentFirstTime(Form f)
   at userclasses.StateMachine.onFirstTimeSetupLogin_ContinueButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event)
   at generated.StateMachineBase.handleComponentAction(Component c, ActionEvent event)
   at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.FormListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
   at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(ActionEvent ev)
   at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Int32[] x, Int32[] y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Int32 offset)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl()
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Runnable r, Boolean dropEvents)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Runnable r)
   at com.codename1.impl.SilverlightImplementation.editString(Component n1, Int32 n2, Int32 n3, String n4, Int32 n5)
   at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.editStringImpl(Component cmp, Int32 maxSize, Int32 constraint, String text, Int32 initiatingKeycode)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.editString(Component cmp, Int32 maxSize, Int32 constraint, String text, Int32 initiatingKeycode)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.editString(Component cmp, Int32 maxSize, Int32 constraint, String text)
   at com.codename1.ui.TextArea.editString()
   at com.codename1.ui.TextArea.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.TextField.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Int32[] x, Int32[] y)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Int32 offset)
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl()
   at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop()
   at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run()
   at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run()
   at java.lang.Thread.threadProc2()
   at java.lang.Thread.threadProc()
   at java.lang.Thread.1.Invoke()
   at com.codename1.impl.NativeThreadImpl.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<init>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.LongRunningThreadWork(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
Originating from:
Message=Object type not supported: [Ljava.lang.Object; value: [Ljava.lang.Object;@e08d4a
   at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Object o, DataOutputStream out)
   at trainingtoolDataModel.ModuleSet.externalize(DataOutputStream out)
   at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Object o, DataOutputStream out)
   at com.codename1.io.Storage.writeObject(String name, Object o)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception means one of the object types isn't supported but it's hard to tell which one.

I'm guessing this line is at fault:

```
    objList[i++] = me.getValue();
```

I'm assuming that due to some different behavior on UWP you are getting a different object type there, I suggest adding logging with the class names of all the objects you are writing.